# Display matrix/image of floats using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas, visualization

I am looking for a way to use HTML5 canvas element to display an image of floats. Consider a grey scale image where values are not 8-bit nor 16-bit integers but are floats (or doubles). I would like to have a javascript/html5 solution to display the image inside the browser using a colormap. Additionally, I would like the user to be able to adjust interactively the minimum and maximum value.

This operation is quite common in scientific imaging software such as ImageJ but I haven't found a javascript/html5 solution. [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) seems to be in the right track for this but is more oriented to color image processing.

Any ideas, thanks in advance

Comment: Well, in a canvas you get 8-bit RGB pixels, so I think the only "idea" is to map the floating point values into 8-bit numbers however you see fit.

Comment: @Pointy, it seems that Hernan is looking for some out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: @unclenorton well I suppose there might be such a thing, but the mapping of values from the floating point domain onto the 8-bit RGB color space is going to be completely dependent on the nature of the data, and also that of the desired visualization.

Comment: Indeed I am looking for something out-of-the-box or at least almost functional. The nature of the data is not really important. Most look up tables work in the following way: (1) create an 256x3 array (each row is an rgb set), (2) map linearly (or with a gamma) your numbers from minimum-maximum to 0-255 and round (3) change the pixels colors accordingly. While in theory is easy, I am not sure to be able to make a fast, cross-browser implementation of this. That's way I am looking for a library. Sorry if the question lead to any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same need for work.
First i would say that I don't offer a library solution but I tell you how I code this.

I choose to make the colormap canvas using canvas linear Gradient.

To apply this gradient on my picture, I simply calcul the min/max of value I need to represent, then I searched for each values what colors correspond considering my linear gradient.

My picture has been included in a canvas using drawImage.

Then I changed the color of each pixel using canvasPixel manipulation on data array.

For interactive move colormap I choose to use JqueryUi slider.

All of this is linked on my code and it was a bit long to do.

Well I added some more complicated stuff because user is able to modify the color of linearGradient using a colorPicker Jquery plugin but it's more or less what you want too ?

I hope I answer your question. Good luck.